Custom WooCommerce Meta Box Not Showing
I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to include a custom meta box on an order's detail page.
I've simplified my custom plugin to its bare essentials, aiming to render a custom meta box. My setup involves using the default theme, with WooCommerce being the only additional plugin installed.
My code:
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'custom_order_meta_box', 99);


function custom_order_meta_box() {
    error_log("custom_order_meta_box");
    add_meta_box(
        'custom-order-meta-box',
        __( 'Custom Meta Box', 'webkul' ),
        'custom_order_meta_box_callback',
        'shop_order',
        'advanced',
        'default'
    );
}


function custom_order_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
    error_log("custom_order_meta_box_callback");
}

I can see the log "custom_order_meta_box", but never the log from the callback function, nor a meta box showing up nor does the meta box show up in screen options (to toggle it on/off).
When I install a query monitor, I can see that the action is recognized:
6   
Automattic\W\I\A\ShippingLabelBanner->add_meta_boxes()
Plugin: woocommerce
10  
WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes->remove_meta_boxes()
Plugin: woocommerce
20  
WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes->rename_meta_boxes()
Plugin: woocommerce
30  
WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes->add_meta_boxes()
Plugin: woocommerce
40  
WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes->add_product_boxes_sort_order()
Plugin: woocommerce
99  
custom_order_meta_box()
Plugin: custom-meta-box

Any idea what I could try?
Thanks!
